# How to replace [object HTMLDivElement] in a string?

Tags: javascript

I need to replace an HTML domObj on a string for example:

```
//javascript

let x = `I am %string%`;
```

and I have an HTML DIVELM OBJ such as this one.

[image]

Now I want to replace this HTML DOM OBJ into this `x` variable 
It should be like this one.

```
console.log(x) // "I am <span> Back </span>"
```

But when I use `x.replace('%string%', elm)`, it returns me [object HTMLDivElement] as expected

But how to do this?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a div element ..? Please show what exactly you're doing to get `elm`.

Comment: Please show what you exactly wants and what you get from your code and please show your code too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are currently placing an object type into the string. Try doing this instead to get the html in string format from the object (if you don't want the tag you can just use innerHTML instead for the content inside the span tags):

```
 x.replace('%string%', elm.outerHTML);
```